# Are all renderscript methods API 11?

Tags: android, renderscript

I am trying to use the float version of rsRand and I get an error for the call being ambiguous. I have a hunch that maybe the method is not API 11 though I am not sure.

```
float test = rsRand(5);// okay
float test2 = rsRand(5.1);// error: call to 'rsRand' is ambiguous
```

The second line (test2) throws an error for being ambiguous though the reference shows rsRand can be used in integer and float forms. Maybe I am just making a silly mistake?

[RenderScript reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constant '5.1' is of type *double*. If you want a float, write `5.1f`:

```
float test2 = rsRand(5.1f);
```

Comment: Yep I just needed some morning caffeine and I face palmed myself before you posted this.